# Absolute positioning not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-position

This code works perfectly in chrome and firefox, but in IE the absolutely positioned divs appear at the top right.

```
<div id="three_pictures">
   <img alt="3steps" src="/assets/3steps.jpg">
   <a href="/users/new" style="position: absolute; top: 65px; left: 50px; width: 204px; height: 256px;"></a>
   <a href="/get_a_present" style="position: absolute; top: 16px; left: 273px; width: 191px; height: 303px;"></a>   
   <a href="/posted_presents" style="position: absolute; top: 51px; left: 508px; width: 148px; height: 276px;"></a> 
</div>
```

and

```
#three_pictures
{
padding-top: 20px;
width: 700px;
position: relative;
background-color: white;
margin: 0px auto;
}
```

I want to have links over certain regions of the image.

Comment: [The `id` attribute cannot start with a number](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-name).

Answer (score 1):

what is the containing element of `#three_pictures` and how is it styled (if there is one)?

if there isn't then what it looks like is that your `margin: 0px auto;` is not actually working on the `#three_pictures` element (because of the `position:relative;` style on it) so what you need to do is wrap it in a separate div which has the `margin: 0px auto; and width:700px;` styles on it.

Answer (score 0):

First you change id name,then you must use this style code for its

```
#stepsThree{
   position:relative;
}
```

i think for its,
best regards

Comment: I use only ids name in question

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what they invented image maps for. They are still valid and supported in HTML 5.